# .Net core viewmodels for consolidating data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

First time posted long time reader. I've done a lot of searching and haven't been able to find anything so please excuse me if I missed a past post or something.

In any case I used to be a .net dev and now getting back into .net core MVC. New to MVC and really liking it!

In any case my question is this... is it possible to use a view model to consolidate data? Basically I am writing a timeline from multiple sources taking only the date stamp and description from each. I am hoping to consolidate all into a timeline viewmodel, but not sure if this is appropriate.

EX:

```
public class order {
 public guid id {get; set;}
 public datetime orderDate {get; set;}
 public string orderDetail {get; set;}
 public int orderQuantity {get; set;}
 ...
}

public class goodsReceipts {
 public guid id {get; set;}
 public datetime receiptDate {get; set;}
 public int receiptQuantity {get; set}
 public order order {get; set;}
 ...
}

public class otherTransactionaldata {
   ... there are many different transactions such as goodsreceipt
}
```

then my view model something like this

```
public class transactions {
 public date transactionDate {get; set;}
 public string transactionDetail {get; set;}
}
```

So I basically want to load all transactional data such as (orders, receipts, returns...) into the view model to create a sorted timeline. Am I going down the wrong path here?

Again sorry for the dumb question. I've been reading like crazy and I'm sure I've missed something so I apologize in advance.

Thank you,
E

Comment: Depends on how you want to use the consolidated data. If they are used only for display, a ViewModel is totally appropiate. If you need to run some Business Logic on these data, move the class to the Business or Domain Layer (and map to a ViewModel from there). ViewModels should mainly deal with View concerns.

Comment: Hit save too early... 

Thanks so much for the reply. Yes I'm using it as display only. For now I'm loading into a list like so:

    List<transactions> transList= new List<transactions>();
      
    foreach (var t in goodsReceipts) {
     transactions = new transactions {
          transactionDate = t.receiptDate,
          transactionDetail = t.receiptQuantity 
     };
    transList.add(transactions);
    }

    ViewData["TimeLine"] = transList;